# iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage

Tags: xcode, macos, icloud, entitlements

Could anyone please solve this? I've posted the forum three I've been using so far.

iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
Oct 30, 2011 9:49 AM
I've enabled iCloud for my AppID. Then, I've created 3 certificates, listed as:

- Mac App
- Mac Installer
- Development

in the Developer Certificate Utility.

I downloaded and installed the certificates in my keychain:

- 3rd Party Mac Developer Application (Mac App)
- 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer (Mac Installer)
- Mac Developer (Development)

Then, I've created 2 provisioning profiles:

- Development
  I selected the App ID, the previously created development certificate and the Systems.
- Production
  I can only select the App ID and the Mac Application Distribution Signing Certificate.

I installed the development profile in the Profiles Pref Pane successfully. If I am trying to install the production profile in the Profiles Pref Pane, I am getting an "Unknown Error" dialog. Is this correct? This profile can't be installed?

I added both profiles to the Xcode Organizer and selected "Mac Developer" from the development profile for debugging and "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" from the production profile for the release version.

Now, I can launch the app in Xcode and it works as expected (with iCloud enabled). If I am archiving the release version and launch the app in the Finder, I am getting:

taskgated: killed ...  because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed

Is the production profile supposed to be used only for submitting to the MAS? Did I something wrong?

steveflack
Posts : 6 (0)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
1. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to pws on Nov 4, 2011 4:23 AM
If you look at the Production Profile in the Xcode Organizer it says you can't install it on devices - which I guess is why it won't install in the Profiles Pane in the Settings app. I only figured this out this morning - that error message isn't exactly helpful.

Maybe I'm wrong but it's looking horribly like you currently can't ship iCloud apps outside of MAS. It looks like we'll have to treat the dev profile like the iOS adhoc profiles for testing.

Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide
Posts : 166 (1)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
2. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to steveflack on Dec 9, 2011 4:42 PM
Were any of you able to sign it with production profiles?

Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide
Posts : 166 (1)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
3. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to steveflack on Dec 9, 2011 5:49 PM
Does anyone know if a mac app should run on my development machine when using a Production Profile with iCloud enabled? Or does it need to be submitted to the Mac App Store ?
When I build and sign with the production profile I get no errors, but I get the "app was killed because I did not have permission to use the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" when launching.

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
4. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide on Dec 17, 2011 12:08 PM
I'm getting this error as well. Please help me!

Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide
Posts : 166 (1)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
5. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 12:23 PM
I requested technical support from Apple, I'll let you know what they say.
But my guess is that to do Beta Testing, you should add each mac system in your mac provisioning section and tell each beta user to add the provisionging profile to their system by double clicking.

I'm betting that the production profile only works by sending the app to the Mac App Store.

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
6. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide on Dec 17, 2011 12:46 PM
If I can't run the app, there is no way I will upload it to Apple.

Strange, but I can't compile any other Mac app right now, iCloud or no iCloud. I've evern tried on a diffrent computer, and it doesn't work!

Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide
Posts : 166 (1)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
7. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 1:04 PM
Wow, you can't compile or cant run the app? Can you compile without signing?

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
8. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide on Dec 17, 2011 1:29 PM
Well I guess I can compile it, but I get this error (it changes slightly with each app):

error: failed to launch '/Users/padsoftware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Scrawl-heofvoywsunchdhjowxkvkoiqvan/Build/Products/Release/Scrawl.app/Contents/MacOS/Scrawl'

It's odd: I don't have sandboxing, iCloud, or entitlements for this app. On the ones I do i get the same error. I have already reinstalled Xcode 4.2.1 and OS X Lion 10.7.2.

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
9. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 1:31 PM
Without code signing I get the same error. This is really annoying me. Contacting Apple won't help, because they are way to slow

Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide
Posts : 166 (1)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
10. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 2:10 PM
This also happened to me when I did not added the mac uuids to the mac provisioning portal, does your provisioning profile installs in your system preferences on Lion?
But since it blows when you are not code signing it, it should not matter

Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide
Posts : 166 (1)
ReplyQuoteAdd Negative ScoreAdd Positive Score
11. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 2:12 PM
If you open Console.app from utilities do you get any extra info when launching?

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
12. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Jose Ines Cantu Arrambide on Dec 17, 2011 2:15 PM
Sadly, no, I get the same info.

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
13. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 2:19 PM
Btw, I just posted this in stackoverflow. [Xcode error: failed to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547201/xcode-error-failed-to-launch)

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuote
14. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 2:48 PM
The problem was I was missing the private+public keys associated with the development certificate... I also, couldn't import the ones I was using into keychain for some reason.
I generated the CSR (which builds public/private keys and adds them to keychain) and created a new certificate/provisioning profile and updating my build settings to point to new stuff.
Somebody said this fixed it for them. I'll try it and let you know if it works.

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuoteEdit
15. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 4:28 PM
OK, here are the results:
Development Profile code sign: success.
Production Profile code sign: failed. Error in console:"12/17/11 4:22:50.184 PM taskgated: killed com.allendunahoo.Scrawl[pid 5772] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed"

I don't get it: the Development Profile has this included in the title: 8W27B5T8XC. However, the Production Profile does not have that. I suspect that is part of the problem. Now, does anyone have any ideas on hw to fix this huge and ugly problem?

P.S. I need the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers  becuase this app uses iCloud.

Message was edited by AllenDunahoo on 12/17/11 at 4:28 PM

Allen Dunahoo
Goshen , CT
Posts : 700 (6)
ReplyQuoteEdit
16. Re: iCloud and correct provisioning profile usage
In response to Allen Dunahoo on Dec 17, 2011 4:30 PM
This is my entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>8W27B5T8XC.com.allendunahoo.Scrawl</string>
</plist>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)8W27B5T8XC.com.allendunahoo.Scrawl</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 5):

You seem like you figured out most of it:

- iCloud support is only available for applications shipping from the App store.
- You cannot use the Production provisioning profile to run executables on your development machine.  This is only for use via the Mac App Store.
- Your Release target probably signs with your "3rd Party Mac Developer Application (Mac App)" certificate. This is required for building the Archive you send to the app store, but you cannot run the application locally.  Instead, you should switch the signature to your "Developer" certificate for running a local release build, and switch back to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application (Mac App)" to archive for release.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I was under the misapprehension that I needed to sign with a non-developer identity to test on Mac w/o running from Xcode. Just to expand, steps are: (1) Set *Release* code signing identity to a Mac Developer identity (same as you are using for *Debug*); (2) Archive; (3) Click 'Distribute'; (4) Click 'Export as' radio button; (5) Select 'Application'. If you have the the Development Provisioning Profile installed on the Mac (check in System Preferences - the pref pane 'Profiles' appears if and only if one or more profiles is installed) then the app will run.

Comment: I have spent my whole day dealing with similar problems. I followed your steps closely, but when I try to export as Application, I get the "Choose a profile to sign with" page which shows "Don't Resign" as the default option, and the distribution profile is the only option without a yellow warning sign next to it. Needless to say, signing with the distribution option doesn't work when I run the app (crashes immediately). Any idea? Using Xcode 5.1 on Mavericks.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'm using a Debug build for 'Archive' with my developer provisioning profile; then export to Application, select "Don't Re-sign", and it works!

Comment: Dug some more, and it works with AdHoc / Release builds with Archive as well; Xcode was just having problems picking up the change in provisioning profiles and needed a restart.

Answer (score 0):

First, I didn't read you entire question (it's really, really long). I read the part about the profile installation and yes it is correct that your production profile should not be installable on your machine. Development profiles allow the app to run on specific machines for testing, distributions profiles are for shipping the app.

As far as your issue with getting killed by `taskgated` you need to delete your app container. Go to `~/Library/Containers/` and delete the folder that has your app's bundle ID. Any time you have issues like this with your app just delete the container again (it's the new delete the build folder fix).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, namely by signing the app using the Production Provisioning profile I am not able to run the application. I get:

12/31/11 5:24:31.024 PM taskgated: killed com.agprojects.Blink[pid 25863] because its use of the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement is not allowed

The application is not sandboxed and there is nothing in ~/Library/Containers/ folder as the comment above suggests.

My best guess is that when signed using a Production Profile the application needs to be submitted to Apple first and will work only after released in the Mac App Store. But of course not having yet done this step is just a guess.